# Getting Array from inside try - catch loop

Tags: java

Good afternoon, I have another easy one for you guys. Im having trouble with getting the contents of an array from inside a try - catch loop and placing it inside an array declared outside the loop. The reason I want to do this is so that I can call it from the main function outside. Any pointers?

Have a look at my code:

I am trying to get the contents of Array votesPerPosition[] and put it inside ArrayVotesPosition[];

Any pointers? Thanks! Your help would be much appreciated.

```
public class Vote{
int voter = 0;
Scanner sc;
BufferedReader br;
String line;
FileInputStream fis;
public int j = 0;
private int voterCount = 0;
public Arrays VotesPosition[];



public Vote() {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter file name > ");
    String filename = sc.next();
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename)));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(Vote.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    do{
    voter++;
        try {
            filename = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Vote.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String votesPerPosition[] = filename.split(",");
        for(String vote: votesPerPosition){
            Integer.parseInt(vote);
            for (j = 0; j < votesPerPosition.length; j++);{
            System.out.println("voter " + voter + "voted for candidate #" + vote);
            voterCount++;
        }
        }
        return String votesPerPosition;  //<-------------- This is what I am trying//                
    }while(filename != null);

}

/**
 * @return the voterCount
 */
public int getVoterCount() {
    return voterCount;
}

/**
 * @param voterCount the voterCount to set
 */
public void setVoterCount(int voterCount) {
    this.voterCount = voterCount;
}

/**
 * @return the VotesPosition
 */
public Arrays[] getVotesPosition() {
    return VotesPosition;
}

/**
 * @param VotesPosition the VotesPosition to set
 */
public void setVotesPosition(Arrays[] VotesPosition) {
    this.VotesPosition = VotesPosition;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to `public String[] Vote()` and use `return votesPerPosition;` to return the data.

(A `String[]` is a reference counted `Object` type in Java so it's perfectly fine to return the instance created within your function).

Comment: Thanks for the input but it is still showing an error for the line return String votesPerPosition; even after changing the class to public String[] Vote() The error states that it is not a statement.

Comment: My apologies; I had an error in my answer which I've corrected. Should have been `return votesPerPosition;`

Answer (score 0):

Try that :)

```
public class Vote{
    int voter = 0;
    Scanner sc;
    BufferedReader br;
    String line;
    FileInputStream fis;
    public int j = 0;
    private int voterCount = 0;
    public Arrays VotesPosition[];



    public String[] Vote() {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter file name > ");
        String filename = sc.next();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(Vote.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        do{
        voter++;
            try {
                filename = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Vote.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            String votesPerPosition[] = filename.split(",");
            for(String vote: votesPerPosition){
                Integer.parseInt(vote);
                for (j = 0; j < votesPerPosition.length; j++);{
                System.out.println("voter " + voter + "voted for candidate #" + vote);
                voterCount++;
            }
            }
            return votesPerPosition;  //<-------------- This is what I am trying//                
        }while(filename != null);

    }

    /**
     * @return the voterCount
     */
    public int getVoterCount() {
        return voterCount;
    }

    /**
     * @param voterCount the voterCount to set
     */
    public void setVoterCount(int voterCount) {
        this.voterCount = voterCount;
    }

    /**
     * @return the VotesPosition
     */
    public Arrays[] getVotesPosition() {
        return VotesPosition;
    }

    /**
     * @param VotesPosition the VotesPosition to set
     */
    public void setVotesPosition(Arrays[] VotesPosition) {
        this.VotesPosition = VotesPosition;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your implementation a bit as following

Change this to Hashtable,

```
public Hashtable VotesPosition = new Hashtable();
```

and the function can be something like follows.

```
    public void Vote() {
        String filename = null, line = null;
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter file name > ");
        filename = sc.next();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(Vote.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if (br != null) {
            do {
                voter++;
                try {
                    line = br.readLine();

                    if (line != null && line.contains(",")) {
                        String votesPerPosition[] = line.split(",");

                        VotesPosition.put(voter, votesPerPosition.length);
                    } else if (line != null) {
                        VotesPosition.put(voter, 1);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    line = null;
                    // Logger.getLogger(Vote.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } while (line != null);
        }
    }
```